# Qt screen orientation change

Tags: ios, qt

I'm using Qt 5.1 beta on iOS. I am deploying my app on an ipad.

The problems I am having regard how touch events are sensed and processed by qt. As long as I keep the ipad oriented straight (i.e. frontal camera is up), everything works fine. In that configuration, if I touch the screen, the coordinates of the point of touch sensed through `mousePressedEvent(QMouseEvent *e)` indicates that, as expected, the origin of the coordinate system is in the upper left corner of the screen.

When I turn my ipad, let's say left, so that the camera is to the left, my ui correctly rotates so that the buttons that I have are aligned to the screen. However, if I sense the touch events as described above, the origin of the coordinate system has not changed, so now it is in the lower left corner of the screen. Because of this, the buttons act as if they were not aligned to the screen but as if they turned around the same way I turned the screen (even if they are rendered aligned) So, if I tap on the visualized button it won't sense the touch, but it will if I tap were they would be if they would have not changed orientation as the screen did.

Does anyone have any idea what might cause this or how it could be fixed?

Please ask if you would like to see code. I did not put any as I would not know what might be of interest and my app is quite big already.

Thanks,

Corneliu

Answer (score 0):

You file a bug report to the trolls about it.  And also check to see if there is a bug report about it already.

http://bugreports.qt-project.org/

For the mean time you could push your coordinates through a mapping function of some sort based on the orientation of the device.

Also calling 'adjustSize()` on widgets tends to fix sizing and positioning with layouts.

Hope that helps.